# In Rails, how to group by count of elements in array field?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given ActiveRecord Model `Foo` with a field `a_of_i` that is array of integers:

```
# Foo:
id, a_of_i
101, [1,2,3,4]
102, []
103, [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
104,  [1, 2, 52, 53]
```

Is there an ActiveRecord query that will group by the count of the #elements in an array column, eg produce:

```
# Foo.some_query returns something like [[count, id], [count, id]...]
=> [ [6, 103], [4, 101], [4, 104], [0, 102] ]
# or perhaps, if easier:
=> { 6 => [103], 4 => [101,104], 0 => [102] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoiler

```rb
Foo.select('id, cardinality(a_of_i)').pluck('cardinality(a_of_i)', :id)
```

Creating a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE foos(
  id   text,
  a_of_i integer[]
);
```

Fill table in ruby

```rb
Foo.create id: 101, a_of_i: [1,2,3,4]
Foo.create id: 102, a_of_i: []
Foo.create id: 103, a_of_i: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
Foo.create id: 104, a_of_i: [1, 2, 52, 53]
```

Thinking in sql

```sql
SELECT 
  id,
  CARDINALITY( a_of_i )
FROM
  foos
```

With AR

```rb
Foo.select('id, cardinality(a_of_i)').pluck('cardinality(a_of_i)', :id)
```

Returns

```
[[4, 101], [0, 102], [6, 103], [4, 104]]
```